# scrape data from a url with file_get_contents ()

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I am trying to read a URL with `file_get_contents()`. I need to get only `$invoice` from the page.

`$invoice` appears on sentence like the following example as a number 789621 :
  `paid 789621`

how could i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

you would need a [simple_html_dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart) to **scrape** the invoice from the page.
then use

```
$ret = $html->find('div[id]');
```

to retrieve the div that contains the invoice.

```
$content=$ret->innertext;
```

gives the content of that div. rest is simple. just split the $content with ' '(space) and get your $invoice